# How to set "Docs" as the main page

Tags: docusaurus

I am using the theme template and I am trying to change the main page of my website.

That is, how do I remove the index page and replace it with the "Docs" page as the main page on my website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Delete `src/pages/index.js`
2. Add the following to `docusaurus.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          routeBasePath: '/', // Set this value to '/'.
          homePageId: 'getting-started', // Set to existing document id.
          // ...
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Follow the instructions [here](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/docs-introduction#docs-only-mode)

Comment: In docusaurus v2 you can't use `homePageId` option any more. See https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/docs-introduction#home-page-docs for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Bart, this was a helpful "bread crumb" for me to dig in for my own exploration to this problem for the v3 implementation

Answer (score 2):

As @Bart pointed out in their reply to the original Answer, successive versions of Docusaurus do not support the original approach.

I have found for **3.x.x** the solution is to:

1. Remove the `/src/pages/index.js` file
2. Add the following to `docusaurus.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          routeBasePath: '/', // Set this value to '/'.
          // ...
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  // ...
};
```

3. Add a `slug: /` (no `'` or `"` characters needed) property to the "frontmatter" of the `*.md` file that you wish to be the new 'home page' for your Docusaurus documentation

You can read my "source" for this answer here: (scroll down to the `Warning` callout near the bottom of this "anchor" section)
https://docusaurus.io/docs/next/docs-introduction#docs-only-mode

Comment: What if I want to make `/about/welcome` the default page?